# Solution for Hackerrank problem: Picking numbers

Tags: c#

I am trying to solve a hackerrank problem of picking numbers or selecting the longest subarray from a given array of integers where the absolute difference between any two elements is less than or equal to 1.

Question link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/picking-numbers/problem?isFullScreen=true

I am not able to solve despite trying different ways. The best try I could give ended up solving the problem but failed in the time limit set by hackerrank.

```
public static int pickingNumbers(List<int> a)
{
    List<List<int>> arrList = new List<List<int>>();
    List<List<int>> arrSkipList = new List<List<int>>();

    int i = 0;

Start:
    int elementToCompare = a[i];

    List<int> arr = new List<int>();
    arr.Add(elementToCompare);

    for (int j = i + 1; j < a.Count; j++)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(elementToCompare - a[j]) <= 1)
        {
            var tempList = new List<int>(arr);
            tempList.Add(a[j]);

            //check if the sequence matches any existing one to skip
            if (arrList.Any(x => string.Join("", x).StartsWith(string.Join("", tempList))))
            {
                continue;
            }

            //check if sequence is present in skiplist added before(below this for loop)
            if (arrSkipList.Any(x => string.Join("", x).StartsWith(string.Join("", tempList))))
            {
                continue;
            }

            arr.Add(a[j]);
            elementToCompare = a[j];
        }
    }

    if (arr.Count > 1)
    {
        //For avoiding sequence with length <= the len of existing sequences and add to skiplist
        if (arrList.Count == 0)
        {
            arrList.Add(arr);
        }
        else
        {
            if (arrList.Any(x => arr.Count > x.Count))
                arrList.Add(arr);
            else
                arrSkipList.Add(arr);
        }

        arrList.Add(arr);
        goto Start;
    }

    //check end of list
    if (i < a.Count - 1)
    {
        i++;
        goto Start;
    }

    //counting the max sub-arr
    int max = -1;
    foreach (var pair in arrList)
    {
        Console.Write("[");
        int x = 0;
        foreach (int number in pair)
        {
            Console.Write($"{number}");
            if (x == pair.Count - 1)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            x++;
        }
        Console.Write("]");
        Console.WriteLine();


        if (pair.Count > max)
        {
            max = pair.Count;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: If you feel you need `goto`: reconsider your approach. Then: add all requirements to the question, don't link to hackerrank. Questions need to be self-contained.

Comment: Isn't this website containing solutions? https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/picking-numbers/leaderboard

Comment: wow i havent seen goto since the 90es

Comment: Sooo.... not to be greedy or anything, Im just interested in knowing If my answer helped you or not

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer I submitted, and it was accepted without problems.

```
    public int PickingNumbers(List<int> a)
    {
        Dictionary<int,int> numberAndCount = new Dictionary<int,int>();
        List<int> counts = new List<int>();

        
        List<int> distinctValues = a.Distinct().ToList();
        distinctValues.Sort();

        foreach (int i in distinctValues)
        {
            int c = a.Count(an => an == i);
            numberAndCount.Add(i, c);
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> keyValuePair in numberAndCount)
        {
            int k = keyValuePair.Key;
            int v = numberAndCount[k];
            int kp = k + 1;
            if (numberAndCount.ContainsKey(kp))
            { 
                v += numberAndCount[kp];
            }

            counts.Add(v);
        }

        int max = counts.Max();

        return max;
    }
```

Now maybe this isnt fully to your liking, since I am aware that many people do not like linq as much as I do, but I would still like to give this to you anyways. So the basic idea behind this is to first filter out the distinct values in the int array, and then connect them with their count in a Dictionary. Now we have a sorted "List" of all values and the amount of their uses in the original List. After that I simply go through that Dictionary and sum the amount of pairable values, or in case a value cant be paired i just use its singular amount. Thoose amount additions I save to a list and then I simply get the max value out of that list and return it.

Now there are some problems with the OPs code and probably a misunderstanding of the task.
When the task says "the absolute difference between any two elements is less than or equal to 1" it means that if you pick any (random) two values out of that subarray it MUST fit the criteria. It does not mean that only a singular pair must fulfill it. So whilst the OPs code would come up with a sub array of [1 2 3 4 5], this is actually invalid. If one were to simplify the instructions, it basically results in "Get the longest subarray with at max two unique values and those unique values can only have a difference of 1". So we are basically looking for subarrays that only contain (1,2) or (2,3) and so on. Another Problem in the op code is that it sometimes skips values. So lets say we have an original array of `(A)[1 1 2 3 2 1]` and another `(B)[1 1 2 3 1 2]`. Now in A things would work out "fine" if we shortly ignore the first issue I described. The Ops code would say

1 and 1 fit, 1 and 2 fit, 2 and 3 fit, 3 and 2 fit, 2 and 1 fit.

Now whilst 3 shouldn't really be in here, we will ignore that for now. But if we look at B we see something concerning its the same up until 3.

Because 3 and 1 do not fit but 3 and 2 fit the 1 gets skipped even though it should be included. But funny thing is, due to the fact that `[1 1 2 2 1]` is the actually correct array and `[1 1 2 3 2]` is the array the OP selects, the returned length is actually correct.

Now lets pick a more complex example:

`[1 1 2 2 4 4 6 5 3 3 1 4 5 5 1 2 2 3 1 2 5 1]`

the correct longest array here would be

`[1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1]`

but OPs code would select

`[1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 5]`

But I will also admit that my own solution isnt the most Optimal one. The credit for that will go to sufertashu (on hackerrank) for this wonderful piece of code

```
public static int pickingNumbers(List<int> a)
{
    int[] buckets = new int[100];

    a.ForEach(x => buckets[x]++);

    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        int sum = buckets[i] + buckets[i + 1];
        if (sum > max)
        {
            max = sum;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Looks ok to me. The only things I could imagine would be: Question and answer presuppose knowledge you can only have if you have an account with hackerrank. That could be considered "bad" - that's why I requested full disclosure from OP. And the other thing is that this is just "giving the answer". It's not explaining the problem (or possible problems) with OP's solution. -- which one if any of those led to the dv, I don't know. Sometimes you just get dvs. I had 3 over the last 2 weeks which I write off as "revenge" dvs because someone felt like it ... it's stupid but it happens.

Comment: @Fildor you know what yeah I didnt even attempt to "fix" the OPs code I just build something new from the ground up. Thanks for pointing that out. I will have a look in trying see whats wrong with the OPs code

Comment: You could also add the knowledge about the challenge that's omitted in the question. I guess that would be appreciated and make both question and answer more useful to the general public.

Comment: @Fildor actually to see the reqs one doesnt need the account. When you get promted to log in you can just press the X in the corner. I only created my account to submit my code to see if it would be accepted. But the short version is: you have a int array or List in which you must find the longest subarray in which the difference between all elements is at most 1. This basically just means that that subarray can only have at max two unique elements (1,2) (2,3) etc. The numbers dont need to be next to oneanother in the original array so in {1,3,3,2,5,2,2} the longest subarray would be {1,2,2,2}

Comment: the function is then supposed to return the length of that longest subarray

Comment: Ah, it looked like you had to have an account. Wasn't aware of the X ... anyhow, it is appreciated (or frowned upon if not) when questions are self-contained.

Comment: @Fildor Oh I fully understand. Now some issues that I have been able to find so far is that the OP doesnt actually meet the reqs. In the source question a subarray could be all 1s and 2s on a array but in the OPs solution if there is a 2 and a 3 between some 1s the later 1s get skipped. Also their comparison acts in a way in which only some pairs fit the difference. So lets say you have the this array : 
[1 1 2 2 4 4 6 5 3 3 1 4 5 5 1 2 2 3 1 2 5]. Their solution would think of 
[1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 5] as a valid subarray even though it isnt since 3,4,5 have a greate difference to 1 then 1

Comment: ^^ Add this to your answer addressing OP directly. I am sure you'll get at least one upvote ;)

Comment: @Fildor I have added some explanations. Please have a look and tell me if you think they are detailed enough

Comment: @Fildor Whats the stance on adding solutions found online? Because someone on hackerrank had an extremly good solution so I added it at the end and credited them for it as well.

Comment: I don't know the official stance on that, I also cannot speak for SO as an organization, but **to me**, I would think that would be totally fine. You presented _your_ shot, you present one you found and credit it to the original author ... should be good.